# Zend Framework Router Getting /module/VALUE/controller/action

Tags: zend-framework, router

I've been googling around and I can't seem to find anything which explains the use of ZF router well. I've read the documentation on the site, which seems to only talk about re-routing.

I am trying to make the format:
/module/value/controller/action give /module/controller/action passing on value as a parameter

e.g.
/store/johnsmithbigsale/home/newstuff would route to /store/home/newstuff passing on johnsmithbigsale as the value to a parameter with a hidden namespace e.g. storeName.

Some help would be greatful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) to map your url parts to modules, controllers, actions, and parameters that can be used in the controller by $this->_getParam('varName').  You can define these routes in the application.ini file or in the application bootstrap.

```
// custom city route
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'cities/:city',
    array(
        'controller' => 'city',
        'action'     => 'view'
    )
);
$this->addRoute('city', $route);

// custom buy widgets route
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'buy_(.+)_widgets/([0-9]+)(.*)',
    array(
        'controller' => 'widgets',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'nothing',
        2 => 'widget_id',
        3 => 'vars'
    )
);
$this->addRoute('widgets', $route);
```

The regex route is kind of specific to my app, but you can see that each match can get mapped to a parameter.